# What's the cleanest implementation of this container of typed containers?

Tags: c++, templates

I have different types, say `A`, `B`, `C`, that all inherit from some base class `Base`:

```
class Base { ... };
class A : public Base { ... };
class B : public Base { ... };
class C : public Base { ... };
```

I need a container, let's call it `Master`, that holds pointers to objects of types `A`, `B` and `C`. I want the `Master` container to provide an iterator over *all* contained `Base` objects, as well as specifically-typed iterators over all contained `A`, `B` and `C` objects. As a storage backend, I'll be using `std::vector`, but it would be nice if this can be switched easily later on.

Conceptually, this is the interface that `Master` should present to the outside world:

```
class Master {

  public:

    add(A *a);
    add(B *b);
    add(C *c);

    remove(Base *base);

    iterator<A*> a_begin();
    iterator<A*> a_end();
    iterator<B*> b_begin();
    iterator<B*> b_end();
    iterator<C*> c_begin();
    iterator<C*> c_end();
    iterator<Base*> base_begin();
    iterator<Base*> base_end();
    // also: reverse iterators, const iterators, reverse const iterators
};
```

**The interface does not have to match this precise syntax.** For example, `someMaster.begin<A>()` is perfectly fine too.

The trouble is, even in this simplified interface, you can already see some code duplication happening. It's much worse in the implementation. This is unacceptable, because I want to be able to extend the `Master` container easily later on, if I want to add classes `D`, `E` and `F` (also inheriting from `Base`). Preferably, I would like to extend it with just one or two lines of code.

All this could be implemented with lots of `dynamic_cast`ing, but that's ugly. I think some magic with templates and multiple inheritance could help me out here. What would be the cleanest implementation of this class?

Comment: Is the order of the elements in the container relevant? In particular, what is the expected order of elements iterated through `base_begin()` and `base_end()`? Can the elements be reordered by type there?

Comment: It defeats the point of polymorphism if you're going to make A, B and C treated as different types instead of as Base*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sketch of what I would do:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead
template< typename T >
class typed_container
{
  typedef std::vector<T> data_t;
public:
  typedef data_t::iterator iterator;
  iterator begin() {return data_.begin();}
  iterator end  () {return data_.end();}
private:
  data_t data_;
};

typedef my_type_list<A,B,C> types_t;

class master : public derive_from< typed_container, types_t > {
  template< typename T >
  struct traits {
    typedef typename typed_container<T>::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin(typed_container<T>& c) {return c.begin();}
    iterator end  (typed_container<T>& c) {return c.end  ();}
  };
public:
  template< typename T > 
  typename traits<T>::iterator begin() {return traits<T>::begin(*this);}
  template< typename T > 
  typename traits<T>::iterator end  () {return traits<T>::end  (*this);}

  typedef my_assembling_iterator<types_t> iterator;

  iterator begin() {return my_assembling_iterator<types_t>.begin(*this);}
  iterator end  () {return my_assembling_iterator<types_t>.end  (*this);}
};
```

That leaves you to implement `my_type_list` (rather simple), `derive_from` (not as simple, but not too hard either), and `my_assembling_iterator` (I hadn't had a need to do something like that yet).

---

You can find a working C++03 type list implementation ***[here](http://templog.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/templog/code/trunk/type_lists.h?revision=46)***. It only takes up to nine template arguments (but that's easily extended), and you'll have to write

```
typedef my_type_list<A,B,C>::result_t types_t
```

but it's simple and free and I know it works (because I'm using this library myself).

The `derive_from` template would look something like this:

```
//Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
template< template<typename> class C, class  >
struct derive_from;

template< template<typename> class C >
struct derive_from< C, nil > {};

template< template<typename> class C, typename Head, typename Tail >
struct derive_from< C, my_type_list<Head,Tail> > : public C<Head>
                                                 , public derive_from<C,Tail> {};
```

That leaves the iterator. What are your needs regarding it? Does it have to be a random-access iterator (hard) or would a forward iterator suffice? Do you need any particular order to iterate over the elements?

Comment: I was hoping for something like this... as well as fearing it. The type list is going to be a bit messy since I'm not using C++0x, so no variadic templates :( Thanks for the answer, and your offer for help with the implementation, but I think I can figure it out from here. This is probably much like what I'd have ended up with myself, but I thought there might be an easier, thinking-outside-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Typelists don't really need c++0x. You can take a look at  Modern C++ Programming for both type lists, usage and the `derive_from` templates. I have not looked into Loki lib for a long time, but it should already have implementations of both. The iterator adaptor should not be hard if you don't mind the items to be ordered by subclass (as compared to insertion order), else you would have to keep an extra vector with pointers to the base type and update it with all entries that are added to each subcontainer.

Comment: You could also take the `boost::variant` path and generate iterator adaptors. `begin()` would return an adaptor that for each stored variant returns the contained pointer, the `begin<A>` and related types would use the visitor pattern in the Variant so that when the vector is incremented it will skip over the elements that are not of type `A`... If you have an interest in this other path I can sketch a solution.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Both are sensible options imo. Accept what you wish.

Comment: @Thomas: I have linked to a C++03 type list implementation, added a sketch for a `derive_from` template, and asked a few questions regarding the iterator.

Comment: For advanced template magic like type-lists take a look at Boost.MPL.

Comment: Just a forward iterator for any arbitrary order will suffice for now. Thanks for your very thorough answer!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you should look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html).
It allows you to store multiple unrelated objects in a container.
The iterator himself has to try to `boost::get<T>()` for his type to reach to the next object of type T.
If the object is not of type T, iterate forward.
If you want to iterate all objects, just return a variant of those objects, that way A, B and C don't have to be related to Base if you don't need them to or just a pointer to Base if all usecases will have a common base class.

Comment: Actually I would say it does not fit here, it requires modifying the `Master` each time a class get added to the collection. Boost.Variant is for unrelated types.

Comment: Not with variadic templates or a typelist that can define a list of classes that are used within the Master container.

Answer (score 2):

Why not RTTI + [boost filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) ? People are usually afraid of RTTI but a filter_iterator with a template filter comparing two type_infos would be just fine.

Comment: Because RTTI might be slow. Scott Meyers once reported VC to use string comparison at the heart of their implementation of `dynamic_cast<>` sometime (when DLLs were involved). Something like this for iterating over the objects in a container might or might not be Ok.

Comment: comparing two type_info usually amounts to comparing two pointers. No dynamic_cast is involved. If OP wants to be able to inherit from A, B, or C and make the iterator work with some involved hierarchy, dynamic_casting will be as slow as any other alternative.

Comment: (You should properly @attribute comment responses. I only found this one by accident.) It's a simple pointer comparison as long as it's only one binary. From what I know,  VC will degrade to string comparison when DLLs come into play.

Comment: I've used a similar iterator over a `ptr_vector` in the same situation. It works well but I admit I am more concerned by the amount of code I type than by the amount of time it takes to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two issues here:

**How to avoid the 'redundancy' in the interface?**

The master class has some functions which *seem* redundant (`a_begin`/`a_end` vs. `b_begin`/`b_end` vs. `c_begin`/`c_end`). My first suggestion is to use Java-style iterators in this case, so that you move the `end` functions out of the interface of `master` into the respective iterators.

Consider this example:

```
master *m = ..;
master::iterator<A*> a = m->getA():
while ( a->hasNext() ) {
    A *current = a->next();
    current->doSomething()
}
```

That way, you have just one iterator getter per concrete type (`A`, `B`, `C`).

I suspect that with some thinking, the iterator getter could maybe be a member template, so that you have just one get() template and be able to say `m->get<A>()`. For performance reasons, you'd specialize those getters to just iterate over specific containers (see below), I guess.

**How to make the iterators iterate efficiently?**

The `Base` iterator should iterate over all contained objects, the concrete iterators should only iterate over subsets of the contained objects. Do do this, I suggest to make `master` contain *multiple* `std::vector` objects, one per concrete type.

Your `A` iterator could then iterate over the vector containing all the `A*`, same for the other concrete types. The `Base` iterator would simply iterate over all containers, treating them as one continuous container.

Comment: That's the simplest approach. However when C++1x will arrive completely this approach will not be as flexiable as the others.